# Php inside div tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

I'm trying to integrate MySql into my webpage and I soon hit on a problem.
I get all these variables from MySql with some other code. But that is not the problem.

```
<a href=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( $goto ); ?> >
 <div class="container- <?php echo htmlspecialchars ( $css1 ) ; ?> -big" >
<div class="container-<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( $css2 ); ?>-small">
<!-- TEXT -->
<div align="center"><big-white> <?php echo $text ;?>  </big-white></div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

As you can see inside `<div ...>` (or `<a ...>` I have some PHP code but it takes the ; ?**>** from ?> not the > from the end ?> **>**

How to fix that because it's making trouble!

Comment: The question is unclear, at least for me. What is the expected bahviour and what is happening instead?

Comment: the href is missing qoutes. Are youe sure that class conatiner big shold include these spaces? As puelo, I didn't understand your problem

Comment: It seems your code is ok! Did you save the file as .php?

Comment: Why do you have a DIV inside A? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href` tags have most likely quotes at the start and the end like this (just btw ;D)!

So this should work:

```
<a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($goto);?>">
    <div class="container- <?= htmlspecialchars($css1);?> -big" >
        <div class="container-<?= htmlspecialchars($css2);?>-small">
            <!-- TEXT -->
            <div align="center"><big-white> <?= $text;?>  </big-white></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Nope, still same problem

Comment: @Jollyfreak Is PHP on your server installed and end's your file with .php?

Answer (score 0):

This needs quotes around the href attribute

```
<a href=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( $goto ); ?> >
```

Like so

```
<a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($goto) ?>">
```

Note that ; is not necessary for a single statement like this and < ?= is short for

Comment: Nope still same problem